# Don't run window.location.href in ajax laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have problem, when i use ajax, code larvel run and i can get result from ajax but this don't run   `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";`,

```
$('.promotion').click(function(){
                var id= $(this).attr('id');
                var url= $(this).attr('href');    
                  $.ajax({
                        url:"link-"+id+"-"+url+"",
                        type:"GET",
                        cache:false,
                        data:{'id':id,'url':url,_token:$(this).data('token')},
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function(data){
                             if(data=='oke'){
                               window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                             }
                            }
                        });
                        return false;

                });
```

countController

```
public function count($id){
            $db= DB::table('promotions')->where('id','=', $id)->get();

            DB::table('promotions')->where('id','=', $id)->update(['count_pm' => $db[0]->count_pm +1]);
            echo 'oke';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script trying to convert server response to JSON object because of this parameter: `dataType:"json",`. Just remove it and You are good to go!

Or: change Your return from controller - return array which will be converted to JSON in front end.

Comment: thank you, it worked, i forget dataType convert html ^^

Answer (score 1):

Remove data type:json and try this

```
public function count($id){
        $db= DB::table('promotions')->where('id','=', $id)->get();

        DB::table('promotions')->where('id','=', $id)->update(['count_pm' => $db[0]->count_pm +1]);
       return response()->json(['result' => 'oke']);
    }
```

And jquery code will be

```
if(data.result == 'oke'){
             window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                         }
```